# Sorting jQuery's Autocomplete Results

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete script that links to my database but I'm sure how to sort the results.

My table has 4 columns: ID, location, slug, population.  The table itself has about 1,000 entries.

Currently, my autocomplete takes in user search for slug, and it will search for slugs but I would like the autocomplete list results to be sorted by population order, the higher population being highest on list.

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Autocomplete using PHP/MySQL and jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

        </div><!-- header -->
        <h1 class="main_title">Autocomplete using PHP/MySQL and jQuery</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <form>
                <div class="label_div">Type a keyword : </div>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input type="text" id="slug" onkeyup="autocomplet2()">
                    <ul id="list_id"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- content -->    
        <div class="footer">
            Powered by Jason's Fingers</a>
        </div><!-- footer -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
// autocomplete : this function will be executed every time we change the text
function autocomplet2() {
    var min_length = 3; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#slug').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#list_id').show();
                $('#list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#list_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // Changes input to the full name on selecting
    $('#slug').val(item);
    // Hides list after selection from list
    $('#list_id').hide();
}
```

ajax_refresh.php:

```
<?php
// PDO connect *********



function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wallettest', 'root', 'butthead', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM population WHERE slug LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $slug = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['slug']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['slug']).'\')">'.$slug.'</li>';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the "ORDER BY" part of `$sql` to be:

```
...ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, in this line:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY country_id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";

Change Order by country_id to population

Comment: Well, it seems you beat me to it. Still, `ASC` would give you the lowest population first.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was scratching by head just then how to figure out what syntax it would be for decreasing order, do you know where I can look at the various commands for that?

Comment: The documentation can be of a lot of help. For `ORDER BY` you can check out this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html).